# React - How to remove and element from an array onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have this array that is formed from strings that I map through jsx and I want whenever a specific element is clicked to disappear by being removed from the array.

I tried achieving this by using `slice()` but I am doing something wrong and I would appreciate if you could help me.

This is how I tried to approach it.

```js
export default function App() {

  const arr = ['string1',  'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6']

  const removeMe = (index) => {
    if(index > -1) {
      arr.slice(index, 1);
    }
    return arr;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arr.map((string, index) => (
        <button
        key={`string${index}`}
        onClick={() => removeMe(index)}
        >
         {string}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also, here is a [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-albattani-gq4kmk) if it helps.

Comment: You have to use state for this, check out [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). The problem with your code is that React has no way to tell that the Array has changed and it needs to trigger a render.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you will need a state (using [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)) for array in order for React to be able to re-render whenever that state changes so you need to add the following line:

```js
const [arr, setArr] = React.useState(['string1',  'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6'])
```

Regarding the removal problem:

Multiple solutions would be possible. Important is to always return a new array instance:

- Use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const removeMe = (index) => setArr(arr.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
```

- Use [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
const removeMe = (index) => {
    const temp = [...arr]
    temp.splice(index, 1)
    setArr(temp)
}
```

Here what your component might look like:

```js
function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = React.useState(['string1',  'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6'])

  const removeMe = (index) => setArr(arr.filter((_, i) => i !== index));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arr.map((string, index) => (
        <button
        key={`string${index}`}
        onClick={() => removeMe(index)}
        >
         {string}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The array comes from an object for which I used `flat()` to get an array of that object values like this `arr = Object.values(originalObj).flat()`. 
How could I use that array (that is formed from the object) inside a useState ?

Comment: `useState()` takes an initial value as an argument: `useState(<initialValue>)`. So you could just use `const [arr, setArr] = useState(Object.values(originalObj).flat())`

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use useState hook. Refer this link. It have a example which is simmilar to your code.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

To rerender a component state or props must change.useState hooks use for change state.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Use React state and the according setter to overwrite the modified array values.

Also note the usage of arrow function with implicit return.

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function App () {
  const [arr, setArray] = useState([
    'string1',
    'string2',
    'string3',
    'string4',
    'string5',
    'string6'
  ])

  const removeMe = index => setArray(arr.filter((_, i) => i !== index))

  return (
    <div className='App'>
        {arr.map((string, index) => (
          <button key={`string${index}`} onClick={() => removeMe(index)}>
            {string}
          </button>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```